# VS2017: OutDir parameter in tsconfig.json how to skip a directory?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2017

I am using Visual Studio 2017 to transpile my TypeScript files automatically. My `tsconfig.json` file looks as follows

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./scripts/ts",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "es5",
      "es2015",
      "dom",
      "scripthost"
    ],
    "outDir": "./scripts/ts/dist"
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot"
  ]
}
```

All my .ts files are under `Project/scripts/ts/modulename/` for each modulename

The issue is that the transpiled .js files are being placed in `Project/scripts/ts/dist/ts/modulename` for each modulename. I don't want the additional /ts folder inside the dist folder. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Could you show your directory structure? I tried and didn't get that extra `ts` directory:

```
$ tree
.
├── scripts
│   └── ts
│       └── a
│           └── a.ts
└── tsconfig.json

$ tsc

$ tree
.
├── scripts
│   └── ts
│       ├── a
│       │   └── a.ts
│       └── dist
│           ├── a.js
│           └── a.js.map
└── tsconfig.json
```